# Java, Firebase, Request notification permission

Tags: java, firebase, permissions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am wondering if there is a way to request user permission with Firebase (or anything else but I need to get the token) in Java for a webApp.
I already know the way in Javascript (firebase.messaging().requestPermission()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request for permission to receive notifications must happen on the client that will display those notifications. Since there is no way to receive notifications in a JVM application, there is no API to request permissions there.

Comment: Actually, my application is almost only in java (wicket) and I am able to receive notifications. I don't understand what you mean with "there is no way to receive notifications in a JVM application"

Comment: From a quick scan of the [wicket docs](https://wicket.apache.org/) it looks like it outputs a HTML client, which would explain how you can receive messages (as long as that client also runs JavaScript code to include the service worker needed to receive FCM messages). But that also means that you need to request permission in a way that makes it into the HTML client.